# Matplotlib: creating a class that can be plotted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to create a class that will automatically behave correctly when `plt.plot` is called on it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyDataClass:
    self.data = [...]
    self.time = [...]
    # stuff

instance = MyDataClass(...)
plt.plot(instance) # plots as if I called: plt.plot(self.time, self.data)
```

I know that pandas does this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a `plot` method

```
class MyDataClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [...]
        self.time = [...]
        # stuff

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.time, self.data);

instance = MyDataClass(...)
instance.plot()
```

[*Minimal and Complete Verifiable Example **(MCVE)***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
class MyDataClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1, 2, 3]
        self.time = [3, 2, 1]
        # stuff

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.time, self.data);

instance = MyDataClass()
instance.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To answer precisely question how to supply a class instance to the `plt.plot()` function, here would be a way to go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyDataClass():
    data = [1,2,4]
    time = [1,2,3]

    def __call__(self):
        return (self.time,self.data)

instance = MyDataClass()

plt.plot(*instance()) 

plt.show()
```

As shown, you cannot directly call `plt.plot(instance)` since `plot` expects its arguments to be lists or arrays. Instead you would need to use the return value(s) of a call to the class.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion more practice is to show it like that:

```
class MyDataClass:

    def __init__(self, data, time):
        self.data = data
        self.time = time

    def plot(self): 
        plt.plot(self.time, self.data)

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Next enter the data:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
time = [3, 2, 1]
kot = MyDataClass(data,time)
```

Well

```
kot.plot()
```

[image]